# In-app billing mPurchaseFinishedListener error

Tags: java, android, methods, in-app-billing

I followed [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial#Creating_the_Example_In-app_Billing_Project) guide, and at the middle of the guide I came across this method:

```
public void buyClick(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
    }
```

I needed to copy it to my app code, and for some reason, the *mPurchaseFinishedListener* (I am using Android Studio) was red (means that there is an error).

when I hovered the *mPurchaseFinishedListener* with the mouse, Android studio said *"Cannot resolve simbol 'mPurchaseFinishedListener'"*.

Now obviously I am doing something wrong, can somebody please help me?

**THANK YOU**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented the `IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` as [suggested](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial#Implementing_the_Purchase_Finished_Listener) in the tutorial you linked?

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
    = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                    Purchase purchase) 
    {
       if (result.isFailure()) {
          // Handle error
          return;
     }      
     else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
         consumeItem();
        buyButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

   }
};
```